# How to call a SQL function from JPA returning a UUID?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, sql-function

I have a SQL function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuidRequirement(name CHARACTER VARYING, type CHARACTER VARYING)
RETURNS UUID AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_dns(), 'requirement' || $1 || $2);
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

that I need to call and get the uuid returned in my java code. I have this java code

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("uuidRequirement");
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("type", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("id", UUID.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.setParameter("name", name);
storedProcedure.setParameter("type", type == null ? "" : type);
storedProcedure.execute();
```

but I keep getting the error

```
A CallableStatement function was executed and the out parameter 1 was of type java.sql.Types=1111 however type java.sql.Types=12 was registered.
```

1111 is the other type and 12 is varchar. I also tried using `select from function('uuidRequirement', :name, :type)` but that didn't work either. Is there a way that I can specify the other type as the return value?

Comment: No need for a callableStatement. Use `select uuidrequirement(?,?)` not `select from ...` and `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`

Comment: That worked except I had to do it as a native query because trying to run it as JPQL gives an error saying that there has to be a from clause. Thanks!